# After voting I'm able to click on pros and cons in vote count

Tags: bug, status-completed, voting

Even if I ideally can't do that due to low reputation (currently 426, but [need](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/established-user) 1000).

[image]

After clicking I got a popup box with error message:

[image]

If I remove my vote, I'm still able to try to get votes count.

[image]

*(there is actually finger-like cursor, its a tricks of gnome-screenshot)*

As you can see, works on both answer and question.

Comment: Looks to be like part of the new voting system; as I upvoted your question here, the number faded out, then back in, for an accurate vote count I'm assuming. So the problem occurs after any vote change.

Comment: @minitech There's live updates for votes now. The fading happens because you're (unnecessarily) getting notified of your own vote.

Comment: Definitely seems to be something a bit buggy. I tried up-voting your question and it immediately gave me the "error occurred" message. I reloaded the page and then it let me upvote. As  minitech pointed out, it faded out the number and put the new one (at the time I did it, it was 5, then faded into 6). But when I clicked on the 6, the +/- details didn't reflect the change, showing +5/-0. I reloaded again, checked the details and it *still* showed +5/-0 (even though the "6" was still correct).

Comment: I can't repro this, but I'm not entirely sure that I understood the question...

Comment: @CodyGray instead of clickable number I should get number in plain text

Comment: @CodyGray and I guess you can't reproduce that cause your repo is far far above 1000 points ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Good catch - vote expansion will only be wired up if you have the correct amount of reputation.